# Как задать значение по умолчанию для чекбокса в AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

На страницу выводится много чекбоксов директивой ng-repeat. Нужно задать начальное значение (checked в true или false) для каждого чекбокса. Проблема в том, что проверять "чекнут ли чекбокс" я могу только функцией (я не могу в массив, по которому пробегаюсь ng-repeat'ом добавить значение состояния чекбокса). Написал вот так 

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="state('forum',f.id);">`

но это конечно же не работает. Я только начинаю изучать ангуляр поэтому многого не понимаю. Может кто-то помочь с этим разобраться?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="state('forum',f.id);">
```